# Building Installation Disk for My Delphi 2010 Application

Tags: delphi, installation, delphi-2010, inno-setup, installaware

Can someone please give me a step by step on how to build an installation disk for my Delphi 2010 application?

I have tried both InstallAware Express Edition which comes with Delphi 2010 but keeps on giving me error message for it continue to look for *120.bpl instead of *140.bpl

I have also tried InnoSetup with ISTool but fail to work, which I believe I am not setting it up properly.... (e.g. failed to include all required packages)

My Apps is a simple database enquiry which I used dbExpress to connect to my ms-sql database.

I have also tried switching the flag in Delphi 2010 for "Built with Packages", no luck also...

Please help....

I am leaning toward using InnoSetup instead, but can someone tell me what is the typical set up is like... much appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dbexpress in Delphi 2010 don't need nothing to be registered when deployed.

You simply need to create a folder with:

1. your executable.
2. all the required packages.
3. libmysql.dll
4. dbxmys.dll
5. midas.dll (if you are not using midaslib in your uses clause)

This is a easy work for an installer.

Comment: If that is all you need, then just open istool, add all the files, and build your setup.exe.  I don't get why the original poster of this question didn't just try that.

Comment: I think he is selecting predefined installation package from the installer.

Comment: I have tried doing this using both innosetup and installAware but failed to succeed.  I guess maybe the problem is not including all the required packages... there is a scan function in InstallAware and I have included all mentioned dependent files but still can't get it to work...  My latest error msg is  "Exception TDBXError in module DbxCommonDriver140.bpl at 0003C9A2"  and  "The procedure entry point _except_handler4_common could not be located in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll"

Comment: Hi Snackmoore, first try to simply create a folder with all the files in a clear pc or a virtual machine. If you forget a BPL the message will be as simple as "xxx.bpl not found", but when it is a DBX DLL you will get an error like yours. When you select diferent drivers in a DBXconnection you are adding specific units to the uses  clause of your app. Check your uses clause to find if you have declared various drivers. After this, you can fight with your installer, but you will not get any more problem.

Answer (score 3):

The best place for support on an innosetup script, is the innosetup newsgroups.  If you ask your question there, they would want to know more detail about what you are trying to do.  Your app is going to set up some database stuff, so a lot more detail is required if you want an answer.

Innosetup is definitely is the easiest and fastest route to a setup.exe, which when placed on a CD, would make an "install CD". (Who uses CDs anymore anyways?)

In Thunderbird/OutlookExpress/WindowsMail, add an nntp server called news.jrsoftware.org,
and subscribe to the newsgroup "Jrsoftware.innosetup.code" and "jrsoftware.innosetup", and ask your question. Post your script. Show your error messages. Explain your database configuration strings, and how you are installing any dbExpress runtime components, if any apply to your application.

Answer (score 0):

We've used Wise Installation for many years.  Very easy to build install scripts. Works great.